# shap.DeepExplainer gives an error related to GlobalMaxPooling1D layer of CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, shap

I am getting an error as below whenever I want to explain CNN classifier with SHAP for sentiment analysis:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [100,128] vs. [100,46,128]
     [[{{node gradients/global_max_pooling1d/Max_grad/truediv_1}}]]
```

This is my code for CNN:

```
inputs = Input(shape=(max_length,), dtype=tf.int32)
embedded_sequences = Embedding(max_features, embedding_dims)(inputs)

out = Conv1D(filters,
             kernel_size,
             padding='valid',
             activation='relu',
             strides=1)(embedded_sequences)

out = Dropout(0.4)(out)
out = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(out)
out = Dense(hidden_dims, activation='relu')(out)
out = Dropout(0.4)(out)
outputs = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(out)

model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

And this is my code for SHAP:

```
shap.explainers._deep.deep_tf.op_handlers["AddV2"] = shap.explainers._deep.deep_tf.passthrough
explainer = shap.DeepExplainer(model_lstm, train_padded[:100])

# error appears at this line:
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(test_padded[:20])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your batches are of equal size and divisible by 4.

Comment: what do you exactly mean please? I am using a batch_size=256.